# Viewing large multidimensional arrays in a C# watch

Tags: c#, asp.net, multidimensional-array, watch

I often work on massive datalogger arrays with values exceeding 150,000 plus elements on the Visual Studio 2015 C# platform. I have so far been unsuccessful in my attempts to find an online/own solution to view the end elements in an array containing values ranging from 150000 onwards. The array appears to show a dotted '...' line after the 124999th value which cannot be expanded any further. This somehow indicates the Watch viewing in Visual Studio 2015 is somehow limited. So, my question is - Is there a way to view massive multidimensional datasets in Visual Studio 2015 via any of its standard Watch options?

[image]

Comment: You could try to add a watch to `myArray.Skip(125000).ToArray()`

Comment: Side fact: The Watch is displaying exactly 1,000,000 items, not only 124,999. (You need to keep zero-based-indexing and the fact that it's a multi-dimensional array in mind while counting)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Skip` linq functionality (`Enumerable.Skip(value)`) to skip ahead the number of elements beyond which is displayed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find a value at specific index you can use Immediate Window for that purpose.